# Generating an update-script with a .dbscheme file as target

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project

In a VS2010 Databasepproject I have a .dbscheme file from a current DB and I need to generate an update-script for my project to resemble this DB.

So in the DBComparison I select my project as source and the .dbscheme-file as target to see the updates I need.

Unfortunately VS2010 cannot update the .dbscheme file (which sounds ok for me: i dont need to update this file) but it also cannot generate an update-script to execute in my project.

I thought of creating a second project with the .dbscheme file as base and then compare the two projects to generate this script but isn't there another way?